# Performance implications of adding columns to sales_order_grid_items

Tags: orders, performance, reports

I have added several columns to `sales_order_grid_items` so that I can see product attributes in the products sold report.

Since products are likely to be deleted I cannot do a 'join' to the product in the report and expect to retrieve attribute values. So the extra attributes need to be stored somewhere.

Does anyone have idea as to the performance considerations of adding columns to `sales_order_grid_items`?

In theory I could serialize my extra columns and spend ages trying to work out how to display them in the products_ordered report, however, are there likely to be performance benefits?

Comment: How many columns are you planning on adding?  What is data types of these product attribute columns (INT, VARCHAR, TEXT)?

Comment: I am adding 3 INT, 5 DECIMAL and 1 TEXT column, so that is a total of 8 columns.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there will be a huge impact on the performance by adding 8 columns to a table. I think it is even better than joining with a products table even if you kept the products all the time.

Also something is troubling me. I don't see any `sales_order_grid_items` table in my magento instance. I assume you are talking about `sales_flat_order_items`.
Anyway, I say, add your columns. It won't crash your website.